# In RESTful API Design, does it have to GET by Id?

Tags: api, rest

In the standard RESTful API, we usually have `GET()` (`api/users`) to return all records for the resource and a `GET(id)` ((`api/users/{id}`))to return one record.

But sometimes, we want to get one record but not by `Id`. For example, a `GetByName(username)` or `GetByEmail(email)`.

We certainly don't want to call `api/users` to return everything and filter out the record we need at the client side.

Some developers implemented multiple API points like:

```
api/users/byname/{username}
api/users/byemail/{email}
```

Is it a good practice? Or is there a better, a more RESTful way to do that?

Comment: There's literally nothing unRESTful about `api/users/byemail/{email}` according to the constraints for REST on e.g. Wikipedia. I daresay some would even claim an e-mail address *is* an ID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on my first RESTful API ever, so I don't think I'm an expert by any means, but I believe generally your endpoint is supposed to look like

```
api/users?email="me@me.com"
```

where you have an index view and you can just send it params